# Are the reported values for flash.system.Capabilities.screenResolutionY and flash.system.Capabilities.screenResolutionX ever incorrect?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, screen-resolution

I have a site where I collect both the Flash screen resolution data using a .swf file and the same data from JavaScript and send it to my servers.

For some users, this data looks wrong - the Flash resolution is very occasionally larger or smaller than the reported screen resolution in the browser.

For example, one user has a `1600x900` resolution screen as reported in the JavaScript, but a screen size of `1366x768` as reported by Flash.

The ActionScript properties I am using are:

1. `flash.system.Capabilities.screenResolutionX`
2. `flash.system.Capabilities.screenResolutionY`

The JavaScript properties I am using are:

1. `window.screen.width`
2. `window.screen.height`

Are there any conditions when one would expect these values to be consistently incorrect in either ActionScript or JavaScript?

Comment: Try to verify if your user didn't have more than one screen because the values returned by flash are just for the primary screen and when flash player started.

Comment: Indeed, most likely those circumstances where they don't match are when the browser is not on the primary screen - so JS reports the screen it is actually on, and AS3 reports the primary screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine the issue lies in the fact that flash player's `flash.system.Capabilities.screenResolutionX/Y` properties only report the primary monitor's resolution. (as mentioned in the comments on the question by @akmozo)

From the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#screenResolutionX): (emphasis mine)

> This property does not update with a user's screen resolution and instead only indicates the resolution at the time Flash Player or an Adobe AIR application started. Also, **the value only specifies the primary screen**.

In JS (and this may be dependent on browser), `window.screen.width/height` will report based on the actual monitor the browser window is on.

So your discrepancies are likely in the scenario that the browser window is **NOT** on the primary display. (So AS3 reports the primary display, and JS reports the actual display being used)

If you need to use Flash and get an accurate value, I'd recommend using one of the following techniques:

1. Use the `stage.fullScreenWidth` & `stage.fullScreenHeight` values which should give you the current monitors resolution.
2. Use [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) and get the data from JavaScript:

   ```
   if(ExternalInterface.available){
       var screenW:int = int(ExternalInterface.call("window.screen.width"));
       var screenH:int = int(ExternalInterface.call("window.screen.height"));
   }
   ```